# responsive css media query breaks - desktop and retina screens

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Here is a site we've built:

http://reenawadia.com/subdomains/staging/

On desktops with width 1920, it looks fine - the white box with the blurb, is square-ish shaped and we like it how it is. However on a surface pro 4, with resolution 2736px width (is this retina?) The white box with the blurb doesn't appear at all! Here's the CSS code I've used to try and make it look similar on both desktop and surface pro 4:

```
/* Large screens ----------- 
@media screen and (min-width: 1910px) */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 1910px) and (max-device-width : 1940px) {
/* WHITEBOX ELEMENTS - NEEDS TO BE RESPONSIVE */
#socialz {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
#aboutme {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
#homebg {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
    margin-right: 1050px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    padding: 30px 25px 20px 15px;
}
#footer-bottom {
   display:none;
}

}


/* Retina screens ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 2700px) and (max-device-width : 2800px) {
/* WHITEBOX ELEMENTS - NEEDS TO BE RESPONSIVE */
#socialz {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
#aboutme {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
#homebg {
    background-color: #ff0;
    margin-right: 700px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    padding: 30px 25px 20px 15px;
}
#footer-bottom {
   display:none;
}

}
```

How can I get the white box look nice on both Desktop and Surface pro 4 / retina displays?

also - how can I make sure to apply correct media queries to the CSS for tablets and mobile devices?

FYI this is a wordpress DIVI build, and I'm using simple CSS plugin to overwrite the CSS, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO,  please take a tour of the help center to see how to ask a good question.  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE].

Comment: Hi Pete, I've asked a question now ,thanks!

Comment: Were you looking to do something like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrxkQd the color demonstrates the different @media queries.

Comment: Hey turtle sorry for not responding but your answer was helpful and perfect thank you